# Relay a binary file with PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: arrays, memory, binary, powershell-5.0, invoke-webrequest

I'm retrieving a small image from a remote web site.  My goal is to relay that image from memory to an API without resorting to writing a local copy.

```
$jpgParams = @{
   'Uri' = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEQ9h.jpg?s=256&g=1'
   'Method' = 'GET'
   'Headers' = @{ 'Cache-Control' = 'no-cache' }
}
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'tls12, tls11'
$jpgResponse = Invoke-WebRequest @jpgParams
```

This stores a byte array of the image in `$jpgResponse.Content`.  I can write it to local storage to verify that it's good.

```
[io.file]::WriteAllBytes('c:\temp\tom.jpg',$jpgResponse.Content)
```

Ultimately, I don't need a local copy.  How do I transform the byte array that's available in memory and pass it along via `Invoke-WebRequest`?  I know file can be processed with `-Infile`, but that's what I'm hoping to avoid.

```
$postParams = @{
   'Uri' = 'https:\\antijerry.com\api\v1\profilepic?name=tom.jpg'
   'Method' = 'POST'
   'ContentType' = 'image/jpeg'
}
$postResponse = Invoke-WebRequest @postParams -Body ?
```

Comment: Usually the solution in c# is to create a memorystream : $ms = new-object -TypeName System.IO.MEMORYSTREAM::new(byte[]).  After filling the stream set positition to zero before reading.

Comment: @jdweng ok, then send the memorystream as the body?

Comment: Yes.  Read body from a response, then put into a request.  You do not need a memory stream if you are just moving from one body to another without changes.